# Boolean variable does not get updated

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, boolean-logic

I've got a simple piece of code that asks for user input and returns a boolean variable. In case the input was unacceptable, the user has the chance to correct herself. But the boolean gets properly updated only when the else part of the if-statement is not invoked. When it is, the function always returns False.

```
def tryAgain():
    bol = False
    print('Do you want to try again? (Y/N)')
    answer = input('> ').lower()
    if (answer == 'y' or answer == 'n'):
        if answer == 'y':
            bol = True
    else:
        print('Your answer could not be parsed')
        tryAgain()
    return bol
```

Comment: try using loop, not recessive function it's better choice in your case, second in your tryAgain() call, you need set bol = trayAgain()

Comment: That works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line of

```
    tryAgain()
```

should be

```
    bol =  tryAgain()
```

And it will work. :-)

Oops... as per what Saeed said... Hadnt read his comment before replying.